# How to write value of a checkbox to a span when checked?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Using knockoutJs, when either one of my checkboxes is checked, I want it to output a value to a `<span>` text, like so

```
-webkit-transition: <span data-bind="text: menuEffect"></span> 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: <span data-bind="text: menuEffect"></span> 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: <span data-bind="text: menuEffect"></span> 0.2s ease-in-out;
```

My checkboxes:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="max-height" data-bind="checked: menuEffect" />Slide In/Out
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="opacity" data-bind="checked: menuEffect" />Fade In/Out
</div>
```

I'm trying to output the value of the checkboxes in the span tag, but cant quite get it to work?

My viewModel:

```
self.menuEffect: ko.observableArray(["max-height", "opacity"]);
```

Any ideas would be very helpful ?

Comment: What does your `viewModel` look like your `menuEffect` is part of and do you have your `observable` on it as required? In addition you can find more details on the knockout site on [**checked bindings**](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) for more details.

Comment: My VM is like: self.menuEffect: ko.observableArray(["max-height","opacity"]);

Comment: Is this the what you are trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/7ZC4v/3/

Comment: @Sorskoot you should put that into an answer.

Comment: I didn't know it was the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve: [jsfiddle.net/7ZC4v/3](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZC4v/3)

The only thing different is that I changed the `:` to a `=`

```
self.menuEffect= ko.observableArray(["max-height", "opacity"]);
```